# user getting access denied although he is in contribute group

Tags: permissions

I am unable to figure out this. we have a SharePoint 2010 page and it has unique permissions set up with two groups one with contribute and other as full control owner group. We have added users to the contribute and owners group everyone is getting access to the page in contribute group except one user. tried reading him and restarting his machine and checked all page permissions document libraries permissions but of no use.Can any one have ideas on this.

Comment: Are you giving permissions through an AD group or directly?

Comment: he is added directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue am facing. I have asked him to click on request access and i got mail and i have given him the access and he is able to get the site accessed now. Its really strange . But i am still confused why all the other users got access and only not him.

Comment: What were his permissions?

Comment: he is having contributor